# Ember Component can't use vendor.js function

Tags: ember.js

I adopted a legacy project that uses EmberJS 2.5.1, and I have a component that is unable to use the JQuery UI Sortable method. The vendor folder contains jquery.ui.min.js, and ember-cli-build.js imports it.

This is what I currently have in my code:

`Ember.$("#cute_table_of_puppies_eating_clowns tbody").sortable({})` 
(Sortable has been simplified for example purposes...)

In Chrome's Debugger it converts to...

`_ember["default"].$("#cute_table_of_puppies_eating_clowns tbody").sortable({})`

The JQuery selector works, but it cannot find the selector. I put a break point on that line, and tried `$("#cute_table_of_puppies_eating_clowns tbody").sortable({})` from the console. This ends up working.

What do I need to do to properly use this function from a component?

Comment: Are you using this jquery function in didInsertElement() method? Otherwise it may not be activated. If so, it might be related with it. [See this link](http://www.programwitherik.com/how-to-initialize-a-jquery-component-with-ember-js/)

Comment: Yes I am! I'll take a look, thank you.

Comment: how is the table being created? Try doing your selector in a `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {})`.